# Can a CosmosDB DocumentCollection have it's partition key changed after creation?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

You can set a partition key when creating a `DocumentCollection:

```
var documentCollection = new DocumentCollection();
documentCollection.PartitionKey.Paths.Add("/partitionKey");
```

Can that be changed at a later point, and cause CosmosDB to re-partition the existing documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried using `ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync` as you would if you were [changing the indexing policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/geospatial#indexing).

```
var collection = readResponse.Resource;
collection.PartitionKey.Paths.Clear();
collection.PartitionKey.Paths.Add("/PartitionKey");

var replaceResponse = await documentClient.ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync(collection);
```

And I got an exception:

> DocumentClientException: Message: {"Errors":["Document collection partition key cannot be changed."]}

So, no, the Partition Key cannot be changed after the collection is created.

Comment: You are correct. The only way to change it would be to create a new one and import it. That's why some folks choose to not use a natural field as their partition key. Rather have a field (maybe `partitionKey` or `_pk`) and populate that with whatever you want upon write. This will allow you to change your mind later and populate it with something different... although that has it's own restriction. You can't change the partition key value in an update. You have to delete and re-create it. That still could be better (incremental) than importing the entire thing into a new collection.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I am going the route of having a dedicated partition key property, but I made a mistake with the casing of the property name in the path string. I mistakenly used "/partitionKey" when I meant "/PartitionKey". Luckily I'm still in my design/testing stage, so while re importing the data is a bit painful, now is the time to be catching these silly mistakes and learning about their impact.

Comment: Yes, now is the time. :-) Good luck with your project. CosmosDB is a great platform from a developers perspective.